# Shadow Root - click in a href under several shadow roots

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom

I have a list of links inside of several shadowRoots. Already solved this problem.

```
public WebElement expandRootElement(WebElement element) {
    WebElement ele = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot",element);
    return ele;
}

WebElement root5_adminPanel = shadowRoot4_MduiContainerChild2.findElement(By.cssSelector("#layout > border-layout > ng-view > admin-panel"));
WebElement shadowRoot5_AdminPanel= expandRootElement(root5_adminPanel);

WebElement root6_breadCrumb = shadowRoot5_AdminPanel.findElement(By.cssSelector("#layout > border-layout > breadcrumb"));
WebElement shadowRoot6_breadCrumb = expandRootElement(root6_breadCrumb);

WebElement root6_domainPanel = shadowRoot5_AdminPanel.findElement(By.cssSelector("#layout > border-layout > ng-view > gdsr-domain-panel"));
WebElement shadowRoot6_domainPanel = expandRootElement(root6_domainPanel);

WebElement root7_selectDomain = shadowRoot6_domainPanel.findElement(By.cssSelector("#domainContainer > domain-panel-item.ng-binding.last"));
WebElement shadowRoot7_selectDomain = expandRootElement(root7_selectDomain);
```

When I reach this `shadowRoot7`, I have a list of items with the same name, which I already created a List to fix it.

```
List<WebElement> rows_table = shadowRoot6_domainPanel.findElements(By.cssSelector("#domainContainer > domain-panel-item:nth-child(n)"));
```

(They are around 45 items)

This will select all of them, in this case all the domain-panel-item rows.

My problem is that each domain-panel-item still contain another shadowRoot (the same path for all of them) an i would like to select a random item, not the first or last one, for example, the item number 43.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chiWX.png)

My solution was this one but it doesn't work because it doesnt access to the link that i want:

```
public void clickSelectedDomain(String domain) {
    List<WebElement> rows_table = shadowRoot6_domainPanel.findElements(By.cssSelector("#domainContainer > gdsr-domain-panel-item:nth-child(n)"));

    int rows_count = rows_table.size();

    for (int row=0; row<rows_count; row++) { 
        if(rows_table.get(row).getAttribute("href").contains(domain)) {
            rows_table.get(row).click();
        }
    }
}
```

Some have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Provide HTML to solve

Answer (score 0):

You *solved the problem* by calling recursively `executeScript()` in order to get the imbricated Shadow DOMs but actually you could have just called `executeScript()` once, and inside got the Shadow DOMs successively.

```
driver.executeScript( function ()
{       
    var root1 = document.querySelector( 'selector string 1' ).shadowRoot 
    var root2 = root1.querySelector( 'selector string 2' ).shadowRoot
    var root3 = root2.querySelector( 'selector string 3' ).shadowRoot
    ...
    return foundElement
}
```

Anyways, in the `for() {}` loop, you should extract the ultimate Shadow DOM one last time, and then select the `<a>` element to check its content.

Comment: But how would I call the executedscript only once? Could you provide me that solution?

Comment: I'v added an example

Comment: I am trying to execute your example but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you give an example with real data?

Comment: @CelsoPereira maybe you should provide an example first.